# How to subclass registration form in django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I wish to have the user agree to a TOS and to also support unique emails. django-registration has two different subclassed registration forms that does this: `RegistrationFormTermsOfService` and `RegistrationFormUniqueEmail`.

Do I have to make my own sublcass of RegistrationForm and then provide both those features? If so, how would this be accomplished? Would the registration form live inside my app's forms.py or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the [source](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/forms.py?at=default) for the two classes shows:

```
class RegistrationFormTermsOfService(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm`` which adds a required checkbox
    for agreeing to a site's Terms of Service.

    """
    tos = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput,
                             label=_(u'I have read and agree to the Terms of Service'),
                             error_messages={'required': _("You must agree to the terms to register")})


class RegistrationFormUniqueEmail(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm`` which enforces uniqueness of
    email addresses.

    """
    def clean_email(self):
        """
        Validate that the supplied email address is unique for the
        site.

        """
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email']):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address."))
        return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

As you can see these two classes don't overwrite methods defined by the other so you should be able to just define your own class as being:

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail, RegistrationFormTermsOfService
class RegistrationFormTOSAndEmail(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail, RegistrationFormTermsOfService):
    pass
```

And it should function, however I have not tested this. As to where to place this class; `forms.py` is a good location.

Update:

A little reading at https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html which tells us that we can pass the view some parameters via the url definition; for instance a form class.
Simply use a URL like:

```
url(r'^register/$',
    RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormTOSAndEmail), 
    name='registration_register')
```

Comment: How would I pass `RegistrationFormTOSAndEmail` to the templates instead of the default one that django-registration provides?

Comment: I've updated the answer. But the answer could just as easily have been found by searching once, either via google or on this site.

Comment: I think there might be two things to not here: it should be url(r^/accounts/register/$' instead of url(r'^accounts/', and be sure to put that line before this entry: url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),